# Hyperlink does not work in footfullcite

Tags: beamer, hyperref, citing

I have been having issues with making this work:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\mode<presentation> {
\usetheme{Madrid}
}

\usepackage{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Example}

Text\footfullcite{\href{http://some_webpage}{Ref text}}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Any ideas or alternatives?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps this is what you need?

```
Text\href{http://www.ctan.org/}{\footfullcite{test}}
```

or

```
Text\footnote{\href{http://www.ctan.org/}{\fullcite{test}}}
```

or even

```
Text\footnotemark
\footnotetext{\href{http://www.ctan.org/}{\fullcite{test}}}
```

With the first option, the footnote marker in the text will contain the link; with the second and third options, the full citation text in the footline  will have the hyperlink.

A complete example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\mode<presentation> {
\usetheme{Madrid}
}
\usepackage{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{tttt.bib}
\@article{test,
  author={The Author},
  title={The Title},
  journal={The Journal},
  year={2015}
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{tttt.bib}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Example}
Text\href{http://www.ctan.org/}{\footfullcite{test}}
Text\footnote{\href{http://www.ctan.org/}{\fullcite{test}}}
Text\footnotemark
\footnotetext{\href{http://www.ctan.org/}{\fullcite{test}}}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\printbibliography
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```